# how to read labview double array in python from tdms file that has been saved as byte array (flatten to string then string to byte array)

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, endianness, labview

LabVIEW pre-pends the array size(s) as first element(s) by default when converting array to string via flatten to string vi.
How to read the array dimensions as well as values properly (big endian vs little endian formatting issues in byte array that represents double floats)?

Answer (score 1):

first step is to get array dimensions

```
    def size_lv_flatten_to_string (data,dimension=0):
        """
        returns size of array strored by lv in preprend of flatten to string from array - single dim =[0..3], 
        2d array has two of these and so on. Single dimesnion is 0 not 1
        labview prepends with array size in tdms files by default
        """
        len1=channel.data[dimension*4:dimension*4+4]  # 0 is 0:4, 4:8
        len1 = len1[::-1] #reverse 
        len_bytes = np.array (len1, dtype=np.uint8) #convert to numpy array
        data_as_i32 = len_bytes.view(dtype=np.int32)  
        return (data_as_i32[0])
```

Next step is to convert byte array to double floats . Note in this example data is 2d array so it has two dimensions

```
x_array_size= size_lv_flatten_to_string (channel.data,dimension=0) 
y_array_size=size_lv_flatten_to_string (channel.data,dimension=1)

d2d = np.reshape(channel.data[8::], (-1, y_array_size)) #actual data starts at offset 8. First 8 bytes are length
d2d_as_dfloat = d2d.view(dtype='>f8') #use >f8 or <f8 to interpret the bytes as float64 with correct byte order
```

d2d_as_dfloat is a double float array